# Listado de Alumnos en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

estoy desarrollando un sistema de registro de alumnos, ellos poseen una carrera, semestre, periodo.
Estos atributos se almacenan en la tabla alumno como un id, carrera_id, semestre_id, periodo_id, y representan un dato de otra tabla, ya que tengo selecciones cargadas a tablas.
Tengo un listado que trabaja con este codigo:

```
function bd_alumno_datos_todos(){
$sql = "SELECT 
           cedu_alum, carr_id, seme_id, pera_id, peri_id, capa_id
        FROM 
            alumno
        ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";

$datos = sql2array( $sql );

return $datos;
}
```

El muestra todos los datos del alumno, pero ocurre que muestra los ids antes mencionados, en donde va carrera sale 3, semestre 4, periodo 6, y asi sucesivamente, quisiera saber como hacer para que al mostrar la lista, cada valor de ID se cambie por su respectivo valor en la tabla, es decir.

carrera_id = 3 , saldra sistemas
carrera_id = 2 , educacion

igual para las demas como podria hacerlo?

aqui el codigo del listado

```
<?php include 'conexion.php'; $alumno= bd_alumno_datos_todos(); <h2>Listado de Alumnos</h2> <table>     <thead>             <tr>
        <th><center>Cédula</th>
        <th><center>Carrera</th>
        <th><center>Semestre</th>
        <th><center>Período</th>
         <th><center>Capacitado</th>
         <th><center>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>    




    <?php foreach ($alumno as $alumno_temp): ?><tr>

        <td><?=$alumno_temp['cedu_alum']?></td>

         <td> <?= $alumno_temp['carr_id'];?></td>

        <td><?=$alumno_temp['seme_id']?></td>
        <td>
        <?=$alumno_temp['pera_id']?> 
        <td>
```

un amigo me dijo que con algo parecido a esto:

```
function bd_carrera_datos($id){
$sql = "SELECT 
            carr 
        FROM 
            carrera
        WHERE 
            carr_id = '$id' 
        LIMIT 1";
$datos = sql2row( $sql );
return $datos; }
```

que tomara el valor del ID pero no ha funcionado

trate de hacer esto en la columna;

pero solo muestra el ID de carrera.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te recomendaría la solución que sugiere tu amigo porque es algo ineficiente (requiere más tiempo, conexiones, datos...). En su lugar podrías solucionarlo haciendo un `JOIN` con las diferentes tablas donde se guarden los nombres que quieres mostrar.

Ahora estás haciendo un `SELECT` sólo de la tabla "alumno" donde tienes claves foráneas (carrera_id, semestre_id, periodo_id) para otras tablas ([supongo] carrera, semestre y periodo respectivamente). Entonces podrías hacer un JOIN con esas tablas y obtener el nombre directamente en lugar del ID.

Sería algo como esto: (ojo, es solo una demostración: no lo he probado y desconozco todos los nombres de los campos en tus tablas, así que puede contener errores):

```
SELECT   a.cedu_alum, c.carr, s.seme, p.peri
FROM     alumno a
         LEFT JOIN carrera  c ON a.carr_id = c.carr_id
         LEFT JOIN semestre s ON a.seme_id = s.seme_id
         LEFT JOIN periodo  p ON a.peri_id = p.peri_id
ORDER BY a.cedu_alum ASC
```

Comment: Este codigo que me das, seria al que llamaria para llenar la lista cierto?, deberia agregar ademas los demas campos alli?, este es la original del alumno: function bd_alumno_datos_todos(){
    $sql = "SELECT 
               cedu_alum, ape1_alum, ape2_alum, nom1_alum, nom2_alum, fech_naci, emai_alum, telf_resi_alum, telf_celu_alum, carr_id, seme_id, pera_id, peri_id, capa_id
            FROM 
                alumno
            ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";

    $datos = sql2array( $sql );
    
 return $datos;
 
}

Comment: Correcto: tendrías que agregar el resto de columnas de la SELECT. Los quité para que no hubiera "ruido" en el código

Comment: @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo Si pera_id y capa_id son claves foráneas, tendrías que hacer JOIN con esas también

Comment: dejame programar a ver como saldria, donde dice select, deberian ir los IDS que estan contenidos en el alumno o serian que los atributos?

Comment: No harían falta los IDs a no ser que quieras utilizarlos para otra cosa. Si sólo necesitas los nombres, la SELECT te los va a devolver

Comment: entonces, veamos, el carr , seme , peri , serian los nombres jejeje

Comment: algo asi::
SELECT   a.cedu_alum, c.carr, s.seme, p.peri, q.pera
FROM     alumno a 
         LEFT JOIN carrera  c ON a.carr_id = c.carr_id
         LEFT JOIN semestre s ON a.seme_id = s.seme_id
         LEFT JOIN periodo  p ON a.peri_id = p.peri_id
   LEFT JOIN periodo_ano  q ON a.pera_id = q.pera_id
ORDER BY a.cedu_alum ASC

Comment: Parece correcto (aunque desconozco los nombres de las tablas/columnas)

Comment: ahora ya configure todas las que quiero aunque si coloco el carr_id, seme_id, capa_id , etcetera, en la primera selccion me dice que es ambiguo, y sino lo coloco, me sale que no esta definido que ocurre?

Comment: function bd_alumno_datos_todos2(){
    $sql = "SELECT  a.cedu_alum, ape1_alum, ape2_alum, nom1_alum, nom2_alum, fech_naci, emai_alum, telf_resi_alum, telf_celu_alum, c.carr, s.seme, p.peri, q.pera
FROM     alumno a 
         LEFT JOIN carrera  c ON a.carr_id = c.carr_id
         LEFT JOIN semestre s ON a.seme_id = s.seme_id
         LEFT JOIN periodo  p ON a.peri_id = p.peri_id
   LEFT JOIN periodo_ano  q ON a.pera_id = q.pera_id
    LEFT JOIN capacitado  r ON r.capa_id = r.capa_id
ORDER BY a.cedu_alum ASC";

Comment: LEFT JOIN carrera  c ON a.carr_id = c.carr_id

carrera la tabla, ON seria el valor de la tabla alumno y el c. cual seria? el que comparara?, donde estaria el que mostraria en este caso la descripcion?

Comment: "_si coloco el carr_id, seme_id, capa_id , etcetera, en la primera selccion me dice que es ambiguo_", tienes que especificar la tabla de la que tiene que venir ese dato (porque hay dos tablas con el mismo nombre de columna). Por ejemplo, si quisieras el de la tabla alumno sería `a.nombre_columna`, si quisieras el de la tabla carrera sería `c.nombre_columna`, etc.

Comment: creo que ya arreglo, modifique el valor que mostraba en la lista, en vez de CARR_ID puse CARR que es el que sale en el select, que supongo viene de comparar los ids

Comment: SI FANTASTICOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO GRACIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASSSSSSSSS

Comment: 123412313 asdasddasd asdasdasd asdasdas  2016-05-26 
41241241241
Administración Octavo 2017 A Exonerado

Comment: este..... ahora me muestra todos los datos iguales para las filas xD, a decir verdad repite 3 veces el alumno y para la ultima opcion llamada capacitado muestras sus tres variantes si no exonerado.

212121212 asdasdas dasdasda sdasdasd  2010-02-04 
12412412412
Administración Sexto 2017 A Exonerado Modificar Eliminar
212121212 asdasdas dasdasda sdasdasd  2010-02-04 
12412412412
Administración Sexto 2017 A No Modificar Eliminar
212121212 asdasdas dasdasda sdasdasd  2010-02-04 
12412412412
Administración Sexto 2017 A Si Modificar Eliminar

Comment: SORRY; CORREGIDO jejeje

Comment: me podrias facilitar tu correo para hablar mejor?